# mongo user can not connect from bash on localhost

Tags: mongodb

In mongo shell, I ran the following commands:

```
use mydatabase
db.createUser( { user: "john", pwd: "mongopass", roles: [ "readWrite", "dbAdmin" ] });
```

Mongo reported a success response. So then from terminal, I typed `mongo --username john --password`, and when prompted for password, I typed `mongopass`.   But the result I got was:

```
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb
Error: Authentication failed. :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:374:17
@(connect):2:6
exception: connect failed
exiting with code 1
```

How do I login to mongodb with a username and password?

---

This is my `/etc/mongo.conf`

```
# mongod.conf

# for documentation of all options, see:
#   http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/

# where to write logging data.
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log

# Where and how to store data.
storage:
  dbPath: /var/lib/mongo
  journal:
    enabled: true
#  engine:
#  wiredTiger:

# how the process runs
processManagement:
  fork: true  # fork and run in background
  pidFilePath: /var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid  # location of pidfile
  timeZoneInfo: /usr/share/zoneinfo

# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1


#security:

#operationProfiling:

#replication:

#sharding:

## Enterprise-Only Options

#auditLog:

#snmp:
```

Comment: Can you add your mongo.conf file, there is a option for auth enable. Did you enable that?

Comment: OK i just added my `/etc/mongo.conf`

Comment: Typically users are created in internal database `admin` rather than `mydatabase` or any other custom DB. Honestly I don't know any use case where it would make sense to create users in any other database than `admin`. Maybe if you run a giant MongoDB which hosts a bunch of fully independent applications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MongoDB auth setting is **false** as a default.

First of all, you should create the root user.

```
//create new user with the root role (also, named root):
use admin
db.createUser({
  user: "root",
  pwd: "pass",
  roles : [ "root" ]
})
```

After that, you should start your mongod service with the auth option, it means authentication is enabled.

```
mongod --auth
```

Also, you can add your mongod.conf file this parameter :

```
security:
    authorization: enabled
```

And start your mongod with the command which is below.

```
mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf //your mongod.conf path
```

Check [this](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/enable-authentication/) out for more info.